# Сортировка массива с игнорированием определённых значений

Tags: c++, сортировка, vc++2015

Необходимо отсортировать массив unsigned int`ов, не изменяя позиции некоторых значений.

Например:
Есть массив {0,9,2,0,4,6,8,1,3,0}
И его нужно отсортировать таким образом, чтобы все 0 остались на своих местах
{0,1,2,0,3,4,6,8,9,0}

Алгоритм сортировки - либо вставками, либо пузырьком.

Comment: Извлечь все ненулевые элементы в отдельную коллекцию, отсортировать, вставить в исходную коллекцию.

Comment: без отдельной коллекции тоже можно

Comment: Что у Вас уже готово по данному вопросу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов

```
void in_sort(unsigned n[], unsigned SIZE)
{
    unsigned pass{}, j{}, hold = SIZE - 1;
    while (!n[hold]) --SIZE;

    for (pass = 0; pass < SIZE-1; pass++){
        if(n[pass] == 0) ++pass;
        for (j = pass+1; j < SIZE; j++){
            if(n[j] == 0) ++j;
            if (n[pass]>n[j]){
                hold = n[j];
                n[j] = n[pass];
                n[pass] = hold;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Не был учтен случай, если в конце нули. Исправил это

Answer (score 2):

Можно создать массив итераторов, куда поместить итераторы на все элементы, кроме нулей, затем отсортировать массив итераторов. Единственное, менять местами при этом нужно не сами итераторы, а значения, на которые они указывают. Можно попробовать использовать для этого разыменовывающие итераторы из boost - `boost::indirect_iterator`. Или можно обернуть итератор в класс с перегруженными операторами перемещения сравнения, применяющий операцию к значению, а не к итератору.

Еще вариант - использовать фильтрующие диапазоны или итераторы, тот же `boost::range` или `range_v3`. В этом случае нужно создать фильтрующий диапазон, отсекающий нули, а затем его отсортировать. При этом  сортироваться должен исходный массив, кроме нулей. Но я не уверен, можно ли это сделать при помощи упомянутых библиотек - зависит от особенностей фильтрующих диапазонов, нужно читать их документацию. Хотя в случае `range_v3` это не сильно поможет.

Ну и влияние на производительность в данном случае непредсказуемо - нужно тестировать.